# Reset children in Collection Info node

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, collections

The [Collection Info](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/collection_info.html) node in geometry nodes has an Original/Relative transform space options. I understand that Relative sets the local transformations of each object such that its final position is the same as in the scene, whereas Original preserves the local transformations that the objects may have.

Independently from that, the Collection Info node has a "reset children" setting, which removes all local transformations. Why is it a separate setting, and not one of the transform space options?

In other words, what does changing Original to Relative do, when reset children is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Original/Relative* switch refers to the position of the *Collection* relative to your current position, and has no influence on the position of the individual elements if the *Reset Children* option is activated.

This has to do with the fact that with *Rest Children* the positions of the individual objects in the *Collection* always use the current position as a starting point.

Comment: I see, shouldn't it be a 3 way switch: Original/Relative/Reset in that case (as there are really 3, not 4 options)?